# how to return username instead of his ID rest framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

working fine but instead of name getting id number only

views.py

```py
class createtweet(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Tweets.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TweetsSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

serializers.py

```py
class TweetsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tweets
        fields = '__all__'
```

pls give me a way to return username instead of id

Comment: what is your current output? and can you share a code of `Tweets` model?

Comment: You can make use of [StringRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) if your user model's `__str__` representation returns the username. Otherwise, use [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) to fetch the username of the related user model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the field explicitly, with the help of **`source`** parameter as

```
class TweetsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField(source="user.username", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tweets
        fields = '__all__'
```